# Accessing JSON with a variable using square bracket notation not working in node.js Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm using node.js. I read an object from a file as JSON using.

vc_channels.json file:

```
{
  "​hangout-room": "hangout-room is a voice and/or video room for anything sfw and not necessarily related to meditation."
}
```

code to read:

```
  fileContent = fs.readFileSync('./vc_channels.json');
  vc_channels = JSON.parse(fileContent);
```

but then when I try to access:

```
          console.log(vc_channels);
          console.log(channel.name);
          item.topic = vc_channels[channel.name];
          console.log(item.topic);
```

The result is undefined: console.log

```
{
  '​hangout-room': 'hangout-room is a voice and/or video room for anything sfw and not necessarily related to meditation.'
}
hangout-room
undefined
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I copy your text for `vc_channels.json`, I can see that there is a `\u200b` (Zero width space) inside the `"​hangout-room"` part:

[image]

In the snipped bellow we can see that the first ASCII code is `200b` and we have `68` afterwards which is `h` and so on:

```js
const x = "​hangout-room";

// This prints: [200b","68", "61", "6e", "67", "6f", "75", "74", "2d", "72", "6f", "6f", "6d"]
console.log(x.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt().toString(16)));
```

So you just have to remove the zero width space character from there. Just copy the output of this into your json file: `"​hangout-room".replace('/200b', '')` Or use any text editor which can show this kind of weird characters and lets you remove it.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that was exactly it. I manually edited the JSON and noticed that an extra backspace was required to delete the attribute name. It was a mistake to copy by swiping and paste.